# GetUserAsync() results in a very weird System.ArgumentExceptio

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I have this very weird error in ASP.NET Core 7 when I call `UserManager.GetUserAsync()`, I pass the `User` `ClaimsPrincipal` to the function and I get an error

> System.ArgumentException

along with my database's connecting string, is this a bug in ASP.NET Core? Should I just go back to .NET 6? I've used .NET 7 and I get these very weird random errors so often

[image]

Comment: Please share the csproj file, especially section with nugets. Also ideally provide a [mre].

Comment: do you mean the issue happened intermittently, and only happened in .net 7 but never happened in ,net6? If so , could you pls provide a minimal reproducible sample for testing?